# Mistaken in Silverman's AAEC Theorem 4.3 ? Where am I mistaken?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, complex-multiplication

According to Silverman's ''Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves'',
p122, theorem 4.3,

> Theorem4.3: Let $E_1,E_2,・・・,E_h$ be complete set of representatives
> for $ell(R_K)$(elliptic curves which has complex multiplication over
> $K$, up to isomorphism over $ \Bbb{C}$), then
> $j(E_1),j(E_2),・・・,j(E_h)$ is a complex set of $Gal( \overline{K}
>  /{K}$) conjugates for $j(E)$.

But $ell( \Bbb{Z}[ \sqrt{-5} )$ consist of two elements $E_1,E_2$, and $j(E_1)=632000+282880\sqrt{-5}$, $j(E_2)=632000-282880\sqrt{-5}$.

In this situation, $K= \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{-5})$. So $Gal( \overline{K}
 /{K}$) conjugates for $j(E_1)$ is $j(E_1)$. This is contradiction because $j(E_1)≠j(E_2)$.

So Theorem 4.3 seems to be false in this case. Where am I mistaken ?

Comment: For arbitrary element $ \sigma \in G_K$, $ \sigma (j(E_1))=j(E_1)$ because from definition,$ \sigma$ keeps every element in $K$.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misread your notation. Presumably the theorem in this case is supposed to tell you that $j(E_1)$ is conjugate to $j(E_2)$ so maybe that $\text{Gal}(\bar{K}/K)$ is a typo and it should be $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$? But I am not familiar with complex multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $632000+282880\sqrt{-5}$ isn't the $j$-invariant of an elliptic curve with CM by $O_K=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

This is because the lattices with CM by $O_K$ are of the form $\alpha (\Bbb{Z}+\sqrt{-5}\Bbb{Z})$ and $\alpha (2\Bbb{Z}+(1+\sqrt{-5})\Bbb{Z})$.

> In both cases their $j$-invariant $j(\sqrt{-5})$ and $j(\frac{1+\sqrt{-5}}2)$ are real.

(recall that $j(z)=\sum_{n\ge -1} c_n e^{2i\pi n z}$ with $c_n\in \Bbb{R}$)